# Windows Server 2012 R2 DFSR folder

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, dfs-r

On my server (2012 R2) the `D:\System Volume Information\DFSr` folder is too large. Approximately 18,5go.

How to reduce it?

The intermediate folder (in DFS Configration) has 4096mo like quota.

What are the differences between `D:\Folder\Dfsrprivate` and `D:\System Volume Information\DFSr`?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think it is too large?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `D:\System Volume Information\DFSR`

1. This is where DFSR (Distributed File System Replication) stores its database. DFSR maintains one Jet database per volume. If you put all your RFs on the same volume, they will all share the same database. So one possible solution is to separate some of your replicated folders onto different volumes.
2. Remove stuff from your DFSR RFs.
3. You can attempt to rebuild the database (thus bringing the file size down) by stopping the DFSR service, renaming the database, restarting the DFSR service, then deleting the old database after the new one has finished rebuilding and you've verified that it's healthy.

> The intermediate folder (in DFS Configration) has 4096mo like quota.

Cool.

> What are the differences between `D:\Folder\Dfsrprivate` and `D:\System Volume Information\DFSR?`

Now you already know what the latter one is. The Dfsrprivate folder, as the name implies, contains data that is relevant to the internal workings of the DFSR service. For instance, each replicated folder has its own staging folder, which by default is located under the local path of the replicated folder in the DfsrPrivate\Staging directory. Each replicated folder also has its own Conflict and Deleted folder, which is located under the local path of the replicated folder in the DfsrPrivate\ConflictandDeleted. This is where files are put during deletions and conflict resolutions between replication partners. There are also some configuration files in there.

Comment: D:\System Volume Information\DFSR has other data besides the database. I don't recommend considering a database delete/recreate as the first step. Database delete/recreate is not to be considered as a routine maintenance task. It is only to be done when absolutely required (e.g. if DFS-R fails to auto recover database). D:\Folder\Dfsrprivate is a junction pointing to a specific folder underneath D:\System Volume Information\DFSR. You will have staging content, conflict and deleted folder content etc here. All this contributes to space consumption.

Comment: @maweeras Thank you for the additional info. I agree that rebuilding the database should not be considered part of routine maintenance, but figured I'd mention it anyway for the sake of just answering OP's question. You could probably also perform an offline defrag of the database with eseutil, but I've not tested. Anyway, AFAIK there is no official guidance on reducing DB size, so it must not be a common problem. Plus we don't have enough context. Maybe OP has 10 million replicated files, in which an 18GB database might be perfectly reasonable.